# Access symfony2 controller from ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am developing a Symfony application, and in a twig template i placed an image,and when the image is clicked, i want to make an ajax request to retrieve some data from the controller.

My problem is that i get a 404 error when trying to access the url in the controller.

this is the script code:

```
$('.info').click(function ()
{
   var optionSelected = $('#pickupCenter').val(); 

   $.ajax({
      url: "{{ path('_ajaxUpdateInfo') }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: { "optionSelected" : optionSelected },
      success: function(data) { 
         alert (data);
      },

      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        alert('Error: ' +  errorThrown);
      }
   });
});
```

And this is the routing in routing.yml

```
_ajaxUpdateInfo:
pattern:  /update/data/from/ajax/call
defaults: { _controller: RedessAlquilerCochesBundle:Default:updateData }
```

And this is the controller:

```
public function updateDataAction()
{
    // Retrieve data
}
```

As i said, im getting a path not found error, so i suppose that i got the url and routing part wrong, but i just cant figure out what is the problem.

Comment: your ajax js code is in twig file or js file ?

Comment: The ajax js code is in a separate js file

Comment: this is the error you cannot access the twig functions in .js file may be you should use some kind of bundle to access the routes in .js file

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I have moved the script code to the twig template and now it routes correctly. Now i have to figure out the code for the controller, as i am getting an internal server error.

Comment: 500 error show there is something wrong in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a twig function in a file that's not compiled with twig.

You could use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).
or pass the value of `{{ path('_ajaxUpdateInfo') }}` through to your js script from the twig template.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem as M Khalid Junaid said. Thanks for the quick response and for the FOSJsRoutingBundle info, but i solved it by just placing the ajax code in the twig template.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) to expose routes in javascript code.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Routing.generate('_ajaxUpdateInfo'),
                data: {somedata: somedatavalue},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    //------------------
                }
            });


/**
 * @Route("/update/data/from/ajax/call", name="_ajaxUpdateInfo", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function updateData()
{
   //--------------------------
}
```

I have written in terms of annotation. You can expose the route in yml as below:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
_ajaxUpdateInfo:
    pattern: /update/data/from/ajax/call
    defaults: { _controller: RedessAlquilerCochesBundle:Default:updateData }
    options:
        expose: true
```